# json_decode иполучние значений из API

Tags: php, json

как получить значение вот из такого запроса 
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2840/?convert=BTC
вот что я сделал

```
<?php             
$cmc_api = get_field("ico_cmc_api"); //здесь подгружается верхняя ссылка
$file_cmc_api = file_get_contents($cmc_api);
$courses_cmc_api = json_decode($file_cmc_api, true);
?>
```

при выводе например значения name все работает, вот ниже пример

```
<?php echo $courses_cmc_api["data"]["name"];?>
```

Результат QuarkChain
Но мне нужно например значение "price"
я пробовал вот так

```
 <?php echo $courses_cmc_api["data"]["USD"]["price"];?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: USD in

Вот пример массива

[image: так выглядит массив]

Comment: `echo $courses_cmc_api["data"]["quotes"]["USD"]["price"];`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie  фантастика, но это работает, пол дня убил на это))))))

Comment: Будьте внимательнее